# iCarousel with page dots indicator

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, icarousel

I'm trying to create carousel with dot indicator which shows where are you currently located.

So has anyone ever created dot page indicator for iCarousel as UIPageViewController, since the only way I currently have in mind is to add round views and changing their color, but that is an ugly and annoying way?

Thanks for any tips

EDIT 1:

So with help of DonMag I have achieved it with UIPageController following example [of iostpoint](https://iostpoint.blogspot.si/2016/08/how-to-change-screen-with.html).
I just added UIPageController under my view with iCarousel and changed currentPage of pageController on carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation.

Comment: Do you not want to use a normal UIPageControl ?

Comment: There is no specific way I want to do it, the only thing is that I don't like the idea, that I programaticly add dots on a view.
Is there a way to do it with UIPageController?

Comment: Look at `UIPageControl` - you can use it without a `UIPageController` ... you set the numberOfPages, currentPage, size, colors, etc... and then you can act on `valueChanged` event (when it is tapped).

Comment: In fact, I think you can find already-done examples by searching for `iCarousel UIPageControl`

Comment: Ok, will check it, thanks